# add subrows in pentaho table component cde

Tags: pentaho

Good afternoon,
I have the necessary data already in a table of pentaho cde. What I want to make it more beautiful and practical is to create sub rows. I do not know what information I have to give so that you can guide me a bit. I would like something similar to the image to remain. Thank you

[image]

What I have right now is this:

[image]
If it can be I would like that when you click on the second column, all of the third column will be displayed. thank you very much